# Прорисовка формы при scroll

Tags: c#

У меня очень длинная форма, выставляю ее свойства `autoscroll = true` появляется полоса прокрутки. Но если тянуть мышкой именно скроллинг вниз, то пока не отпустишь мышку, форма не обновляется. Тоже самое пробовал и с компонентой `Panel`.

Можно ли как то заставить форму прорисовываться по мере прокрутки ?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо еще выставить свойство формы `DoubleBuffered = true`.